# I get nil while trying to populate a cell in cellforitem (UICollectionView)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I am building a collection view for the first time. My cell has :

- An image view
- a label.

In order to populate the cell I built 2 arrays of strings :

- one for the label
- the other with sfsymbols names.

In the "cell for item function", I get a nil value even though I am using indexpath.row in order get the data in the arrays.

I tried to use "if let" to avoid the fatal error, like so:

```
  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? sectorCell {
            cell.sectorImage.image = UIImage(systemName: sfSymbolsArray[indexPath.row])
            cell.sectorName.text = sectorsArray[indexPath.row]
            
            return cell
        }
            
    
        //return cell
    }
```

however this method does not allow me to "return cell" and the error remains.

Advice ?

Comment: what is reuseIdentifier of  sectorCell ? is it created programatically or in storyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

`dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` will return nil if you haven’t registered the reuse identifier. You will need to set the cells reuse identifier - either in the storyboard or by calling `register:forCellReuseIdentifier:` on your collection view:

```
func init(coder: Coder) {
   ...
   collectionView.register(sectorCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: “sectorCellIdentifier”)
}
```

Then in your `cellForItemAt` function, use “sectorCellIdentifier” (or whatever identifier you’ve chosen).

Comment: I created the reuse identifier via storyboards. I tried copying the whole string. I also tried attaching the string to a variable (i.e : private let reuseIdentifier = "sectorCell"). I still get the same error with both methods

Comment: Have you set the class type of the cell as well? If you remove “as? sectorCell” is it still nil?

Comment: I found the error. I used "let" rather than "var" for the custom cell, which would not allow me to modify its values. It is working now, just the appearance that I have to work on. Many thanks all